# Issue with tensorflow shape with b/w images

Tags: python, image, image-processing, colors, tensorflow

I'm a tensorflow beginner so please bear with me.
Right now I am trying to modifiy an existing python programm for a CNN that creates a superresolution image. The Code can be found here if you're interested: https://github.com/pinae/Superresolution

The input tensor has the shape <5,240,320,3>, 5 being batch size, 240 and 320 the size of the image(s) and 3 being the number of channels (RGB). I want to modify this program for black and white images, so just 1 channel -> <5,240,320,1>

First, I convert the testing and validation images to b/w:

```
   image = image.convert('L')
```

The images then get written into an array and this is where my issue starts. The array will have the size of <240,320>. The array of 5 images get written into a list and is handed over to tensorflow.

Tensorflow expects a <5,240,320,1> tensor but the list of images has the shape <5,240,320>, so one dimension is missing. I tried adding a dimension with np.expand_dims and the like but no success.

```
    input_batches = np.expand_dims(input_batches, axis=-1)
```

Why does the index of channels of a tensorflow placeholder seem to start at 1 while the index of resolution starts at 0?

I'm sure there will be many more issues down the road like adjusting the filters but this is where I'm stuck now.

Comment: Dont have time to write up a full answer and look into this but if you have a look at the MNIST examples, they are black and white and should give you some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the code. I believe the problem may be deeper rooted. With the limited information, I assume you are using `network.py`. In there, we see this in line 16:

```
    self.inputs = tf.placeholder(
        tf.float32, [batch_size, dimensions[1], dimensions[0], 3], name='input_images'
    )
```

The depth dimension is already hard coded as `3`. You would have to edit that as well, amongst possibly many other things.

As a caveat, most super-resolution CNNs use small patch sizes. Definitely not `(240, 320)`, I suspect it will be hard to converge as the batch size is small.

Comment: I changed that to dimension = 1 already. I'm sure that I'll have to make many changes down the road, but first I'd need to solve this problem.

Comment: It'd be good if you can post more information. I've no idea where `input_batches` is fed to for one.

Comment: input_batches is just a list of arrays of images. This is fed into the tensor self.inputs (and other tensors as well). The tensor has the shape 5,240,320,1 but my list has the shape 5,240,320. I've tried expand_dims but that does not work.

Comment: It's weird that `np.expand_dims` doesn't work. I'm pretty sure the error lies somewhere else. Have you also checked the shape of `target_batches`?

Comment: it did work. My problem was something else. I'm currently training a set of black and white images, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a tensor of shape [5,240,320] you can reshape it to be [5,240,320,1] with this one command

```
correctSizedTensor = tf.reshape( wrongSizedTensor, [5,240,320,1] )
```

Comment: is it possible to reshape a list?

Comment: yes it is possible, so long as that list is put into tensorflow.  else wise use the numpy function like so:  **myNumpyList.reshape( (5,240,320,1) )**

Comment: hmm. I have tried using **input_batches = np.expand_dims(input_batches, axis=4)** but it does not work. Tensorflow stills sees the wrong shape. If I however change the axis to 3, then a dimension will appear in 3rd place (5,240,1,320). When axis is 4, a dimension will not appear in 4th place which is what I want (5,240,320,1). Axis = 1 or 2 also works, but not 4 or -1.